# setTimeout not working in async code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, settimeout

Following is my angular controller code -

```
$scope.visibility = true;
$http.get("/api/getempl").then(function(response){
    if (response.status == 200) {
        $scope.empData = response.data.data;
        (function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $scope.visibility = false;
            }, 4000);
        })();
    }
});
```

What I am trying is to show Loading Image till data not fetched and flagging `$scope.visibility` on response basis -

```
.col-md-12(ng-show="visibility")
  h1 LOADING
.col-md-12(ng-show="!visibility")
  // DATA IN TABLE
```

Now LOADING text is always visible as I am expecting once data fetched, after a delay show table data but its not working, let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Why not just show the data when it's available, what makes you think your users want to wait another 4 seconds ?

Comment: @adeneo actually when I am pouring the data in the table there is a little flickering for some time and then every thing sets..so I am making a delay..4 sec delay is just for the testing purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use $timeout

Angular's wrapper for window.setTimeout. The fn function is wrapped into a try/catch block and delegates any exceptions to $exceptionHandler service.

```
$scope.visibility = true;
$http.get("/api/getempl").then(function(response){
    if (response.status == 200) {
        $scope.empData = response.data.data;

            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.visibility = false;
            }, 4000);

    }
});
```

Comment: $timeout is asynchron function , what you mean ?

Comment: My bad ..I need to `inject` $timeout in my controller..thx +1 and green tick :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) instead of `setTimeout`:

```
$scope.visibility = true;
$http.get("/api/getempl").then(function(response){
    if (response.status == 200) {
        $scope.empData = response.data.data;
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.visibility = false;
        }, 4000);
    }
});
```

See the working example: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cqgb2wgq/3/)

Comment: My bad ..I need to inject `$timeout` in my controller..thx +1